# What is the biblical basis to prove the perpetual virginity of Mary?

Tags: catholicism, biblical-basis, virgin-mary, perpetual-virginity

Roman Catholics believe that the blessed Mary not only was a virgin up until the birth of Christ but remained a perpetual virgin from then until the moment of her death. What is the biblical basis for this?